# Webhook for local Jenkins and hosted Gitlab?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to make a webhook for when I push something to Git lab. Git lab is hosted by school and I've installed Jenkins locally. Now when I want to make a webhook http://localhost:8080/project/timely-frontend
Gitlabs says: "URL is blocked: Requests to localhost are not allowed". Are there any other possible ways to make a push webhook?

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins and Gitlab are both installed on the same internal (school) network, try using the internal private IP address of Jenkins as the webhook URL instead of localhost.

On the Jenkins host, this can be obtained using a command line `ip addr show` on Ubuntu and put that in the Gitlab webhook.

Keep in mind that especially if Jenkins is running on a non-standard port (8080), other firewalls outside your control could still block the connection.